# dots in the viewFlipper view

Tags: android

I have a ViewFlipper view with two views inside it -

```
        <ListView 
            android:dividerHeight="5dip" 
            android:id="@android:id/list" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
            android:divider="@android:color/black">
        </ListView>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TextView>                     
    </ViewFlipper>
```

How do i programmtically DRAW two little dots (or as many dots as there are children views inside the viewFlipper view)?

Should i override onDraw()?

My activity that inflates this ViewFlipper layout extends ListActivity...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider overriding dispatchDraw method (invoke super method and after that draw dots) because if you override onDraw the children's content will cover your dots.

Or create extension of horizontal linear layout containing view flipper at the top and some component at the bottom which manages ImageViews to show dots (or draws them manually).

```
public class CustomViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
     public TableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
     }

     @Override
     protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

       drawDots(canvas);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Any idea how i could override DispatchDraw()? My activity extends ListActivity and i am calling setContentView() with the layout that contains the ViewFlipper in it. I can only override DispatchDraw() for classes that extend ViewGroup or View. I am unable to figure out how to make that jump from my activity extending ListActivity to that of ViewGroup. Any examples?

Comment: Just create your own class that extends from ViewFlipper. And there you can draw everything you want.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://asishinwp.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/android-viewflipper-with-page-indicator/